# OpenGL Mipmap Texture_2D

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, mipmaps

I am very new in openGL and I use LWJGL.

I do not know how to see if "Mipmaps are working"

This is how I load a Image (64x64) :

```
private int loadPNGTexture(String filename) {
    ByteBuffer buf = null;
    int tWidth = 0;
    int tHeight = 0;

    try {

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(filename).getPath());
        decoder = new PNGDecoder(in);

        tWidth = decoder.getWidth();
        tHeight = decoder.getHeight();


        buf = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(4 * decoder.getWidth() * decoder.getHeight());
        decoder.decode(buf, decoder.getWidth() * 4, PNGDecoder.Format.RGBA);
        buf.flip();

        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    int texId = GL11.glGenTextures();
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);

    GL11.glPixelStorei(GL11.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, tWidth, tHeight, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
    GL30.glGenerateMipmap(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);

    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    return texId;
}
```

And this is how I draw my Image :

```
public void drawGL() {

    GL11.glPushMatrix();

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, playerTextures[0]);

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(decoder.getWidth(), 0);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(decoder.getWidth(), decoder.getWidth());

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0, decoder.getWidth());

    GL11.glEnd();

    GL11.glPopMatrix();

}
```

The draw is correct, I can see my Image but if I change the DisplayMode (from 800x600 to 1280x960), the Image is not growing up. So the problem is that I need the Image grow up to scale with the resolution.

Comment: A little more information would help here.  Is your tristrip full screen?  If so, then your texture is smaller than the polygon, and you'll never use a mipmap; you'll only be magnifying the texture (i.e., using the mag filter)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No It could not be fullscreen only 800x600, 1280x960 or 1600x1200. My Image should be 32x32 if the resolution is 800x600 and 64x64 if the resolution is 1600x1200. The texture is a square drawed by 2 triangles_strip